"Spanning trees" for connected linear hypergraphs
Starting point. For every simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ there is $E_0\subseteq E$ such that $(V,E_0)$ is minimally connected: the spanning tree. The goal of this question is to find out whether the same thing holds for "graph-like" hypergraphs.
Formulation for hypergraphs. We call a hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ with $V\neq \emptyset$ connected if for all non-empty $X\subseteq V$ with $X\neq V$ there is $e\in E$ with $$e\cap X \neq \emptyset \neq e \cap (V\setminus X).$$
(Trivially, for every connected hypergraph, we have $\bigcup E = V$.)
We say that $H=(V,E)$ is linear if the cardinality of the intersection of any two distinct edges is at most $1$.
Question. If $H =(V,E)$ is a linear connected hypergraph, is there $E_0\subseteq E$ with the following properties?

$(V, E_0)$ is connected, and
whenever $e_0\in E_0$, the hypergraph $\big(V, (E_0\setminus\{e_0\})\big)$ is no longer connected.

Note. There is an easy example showing that if we consider all connected hypergraphs, the answer is negative.

Do you allow infinite edges?

Yes, no restriction on the edges

Counterexample. Let $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Let $V=\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $e_n=\{n\}\times\mathbb N$ and $f_n=[n]\times\{n\}$. Let $E=\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{f_n:2\le n\in\mathbb N\}$. Then $G=(V,E)$ is a connected linear hypergraph. For $E_0\subseteq E$ the spanning subhypergraph $G_0=(V,E_0)$ is connected if and only if $E_0$ contains all the edges $e_n$ and infinitely many of the edges $f_n$.
Another counterexample, this one with finite edges. Let $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ as before, but $E=\{e_{m,n}:m,n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{f_m:m\in\mathbb N\}$ where $e_{m,n}=\{m\}\times\{2n-1,2n,2n+1\}$ and $f_m=[m]\times\{2m-1\}$.
